# Web Api Controller does not write to a file

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to create some custom logging in my Web APi project, so just for the moment to keep things simple I have the following code in the Controller method.

```
bool IsExist = System.IO.Directory.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Logs/"));
if (!IsExist)
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Logs/"));

StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Logs/") + "WooOrders.log"));

writer.WriteLine("WooOrders", "got here ");
writer.Flush();
writer.Close();
```

When I run my code the file doesn't seem to get created.

From within IIS I've made a Logs virtual directory that links to a physical directory under the website.

[image]

Comment: You should write to the static file folder(`wwwroot`) otherwise you should set an extra static file folder.

Comment: Looks like in Path.Combine you should replace + to comma(,). Also, validate you is security access permissions, bc by default is cannot write anything to the hard drive

Comment: I dont have a wwwroot folder. This is webApi Service. How would I make the Logs folder above static?